# SQL Query with Regular Expression in LIKE function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a requirement where in I want to filter all rows in a table, which have a keyword 'Risk' in the description but not 'F Risk'. For example, in the following test data, the query should select rows 1,5,6 and 7.

[image]

However, when I am using the below query, it is eliminating id 1 (as it meets the second half of the condition) and just returning 5,6 and 7.

```
SELECT *
FROM TestDesc
WHERE ([desc] LIKE '%Risk%' AND [desc] NOT LIKE '%F Risk%')
```

I believe I would have to use regular expressions to achieve the desired result, but I am not very familiar with regular expression.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to tweak the search for "F Risk":

```
SELECT *
FROM TestDesc
WHERE [desc] LIKE '%Risk%' AND [desc] NOT LIKE '%[ (]F Risk%'
```

Comment: Ahh..thanks @Gordon. It worked. This condition is basically checking for a space or a ( before 'F Risk'. Correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: Since [] is not ANSI SQL, you could have used three like's to deal with the space and open parens.

Comment: @Abhi . . . Exactly.